# Setting up icon and splash screen in ember cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ember.js

I replaced all the splash screens and icon in app/ember-cordova/cordova/platform/android/res into the new splashscreens for different sizes. On building cordova again, it still shows the older apk.

```
ember cdv:build --platform=android
```

How do you change icon and splash screen?

Comment: You have to replace them in the `<project-root>/resources` folder, not somewhere in the `platforms` directory because everything in platforms is generated if you run a build command.

Comment: Where does the linking exist to the image location?

Comment: What linking? I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: as in, if we add the image in project/resources/, how does cordova know where it is, and what file, while building the app?

Comment: Ah because you have entries like this one for icon and splashscreen for every platform in config.xml: `<icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />`